# Messages cannot be resolved error when imported Jenkins plugin as Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins-plugins

I am new to plugin development for Jenkins. I have imported Jenkins plugin as maven project, i am using  `Luna Eclipse` with `jdk1.7` and `Maven3.0`.

The imported project i have build 'mvn using clean install' and it build successfully, but still I get error which says  **Messages cannot be resolved**.

I tried cleaning, building, refreshing the project, change of work-space, also tried,

click this folder in the package explorer and add it from the context menu by following `Build Path > Use as Source Folder` as suggested form Jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+plugin+development+with+Eclipse

but still I have the same issue. Although this does't give any error while building the project, it appears as error on folders. How do I overcome this , any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer to this, its very easy.

If you see your Eclipse reporting that the "Messages" classes do not exist, make sure Eclipse is treating your target/generated-sources/localizer directory as one of the source root directory. If not, click this folder in the package explorer and add it from the context menu by following "Build Path > Use as Source Folder"

Lets try to translate this to English,

Search for folder called `genarated-source` in your imported folder in your Eclipse.
you will find it under : ex- **jenkins-ci**------>**traget**---->**generated-sources**---->**localizer**

Right click on **localizer** select ***"Build Path > Use as Source Folder"***

where **jenkins-ci** is the main folder which you imported into your eclipse.

Comment: target folder will only be visible when you " mvn clean install " your project/plugin which you imported.  At least once :-)